# Reusing jQuery code inside a Prototype Rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

javascript noob here. So I'm trying to use this s3 uploader jQuery example [here](https://github.com/iwasrobbed/Rails3-S3-Uploader-Plupload)
in my Rails 3 app which uses Prototype. After reading the [jquery doc](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries) on how to use Prototype and jQuery and avoiding conflict, I am confused on where to use the `jQuery.noConflict();` function.

I planned to use the

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   // Do jQuery stuff using $
   $("div").hide();
 });
```

to wrap any jQuery code,  but it doesn't seem to function.

My question is

Should I wrap the code in jquery.js ? the js files from plupload? The javascript code in the helper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good example of where to put .noConflict() here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

Comment: Does it mean I should wrap any jQuery code except the code in jquery.js ?

Comment: Any jQuery code that uses $ should be inside the document.ready. You shouldn't need to wrap code in other .js files, as long as they are called from within document.ready

Comment: That was my question. Thanks!